# Oblique table view cells in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

How can I implement this? A table view with oblique cells. I was thinking first to make the cells overlap and cut out a piece, but I can't make it work. 
Now the single solution I can think of is to download the second image in first cell and cut out the top triangle and add to the first cell. But that wouldn't be too optimal memory wise and processing wise if the user is scrolling through the list.

I appreciate any advice, thank you!

[image]

Comment: Is it a full 3D scene with a perspective and a vanishing point, or a flat 2D skew effect?

Comment: You can add two views with background images or two UIImageViews and use UIBezierPath

Comment: Do you want these cells to be scrolled ? And if yes what will be the image at the bottom be like ?

Comment: these are just placeholders to show, basically it is a tableview and these are the cells, so you can scroll down to see more. I am thinking on how to solve the oblique separator, is it possible with UITableView or UICollectionView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it the following way. I used **UICollectionView** in the end because I couldn't find a way to overlap nicely the cells from **UITableView**. So first I made a custom layout which looks like this:

**CustomCollectionViewFlowLayout.swift**

```
import UIKit

class CustomCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func collectionViewContentSize() -> CGSize {
        let xSize = self.itemSize.width
        let ySize = CGFloat(self.collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(0)) * self.itemSize.height

        var size = CGSizeMake(xSize, ySize)
        if self.collectionView!.bounds.size.width > size.width {
            size.width = self.collectionView!.bounds.size.width
        }
        if self.collectionView!.bounds.size.height > size.height {
            size.height = self.collectionView!.bounds.size.height
        }
        return size
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [AnyObject]? {
        let attributesArray = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect) as! [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]
        let numberOfItems = self.collectionView?.numberOfItemsInSection(0)

        for attribute in attributesArray {
            let xPosition = attribute.center.x
            var yPosition = attribute.center.y

            if attribute.indexPath.row == 0 {
                attribute.zIndex = Int(INT_MAX)
            } else {
                yPosition -= CGFloat(60 * attribute.indexPath.row)
                attribute.zIndex = numberOfItems! - attribute.indexPath.row
            }

            attribute.center = CGPointMake(xPosition, yPosition)
        }

        return attributesArray
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes! {
        return UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWithIndexPath: indexPath)
    }

}
```

Then I used paths and shapes to cut out that part and also draw a white rectangle. So it looks like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ChallengeCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ChallengeCollectionViewCell

    cell.challengeImage.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: STATIC_IMAGE_URL), completed: nil)

    let trianglePath = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathMoveToPoint(trianglePath, nil, 0, 0)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(trianglePath, nil, 0, cell.challengeImage!.frame.size.height)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(trianglePath, nil, cell.challengeImage!.frame.size.width, cell.challengeImage!.frame.size.height - 50)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(trianglePath, nil, cell.challengeImage!.frame.width, 0)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(trianglePath, nil, 0, 0)
    CGPathCloseSubpath(trianglePath)

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.frame = cell.challengeImage!.frame
    shapeLayer.path = trianglePath

    cell.challengeImage.layer.mask = shapeLayer
    cell.challengeImage.layer.masksToBounds = true

    let linePath = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathMoveToPoint(linePath, nil, 0, cell.challengeImage!.frame.size.height)
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(linePath, nil, cell.challengeImage!.frame.size.width, cell.challengeImage!.frame.size.height - 50)
    CGPathCloseSubpath(linePath)

    let lineShape = CAShapeLayer()
    lineShape.path = linePath
    lineShape.lineWidth = 10
    lineShape.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor

    cell.challengeImage.layer.addSublayer(lineShape)

    return cell
}
```

I hope it will be useful for someone who runs into the same problem. Thanks and best wishes!

Comment: Hi, How you override collectionViewContentSize if that function isn't in UICollectionViewFLowlayout ?

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar like this but I didn't use `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`.

What I use is having one `UIImageView`(AView) on top of the other `UIImageView`(BView) in view hieararchy. So I add `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to BView .And at the top of BView I've added a seperator view(when VC load user could not see it). And I basically animating BView however I want.

But since they are not cells in UITableView you can't give "pulling" behavior to user which is a UX disadvantage for your app.